# angular directive $watch sibling height change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to listen for a sibling element's height change but so far I can't get this to work..... `element[0].nextElementSibling.clientHeight` returns the correct value when initializing but doesn't update....

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('someApp').directive('heightdir', function($window) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element) {

        // Adjust height.
        scope.calcCommentsHeight = function() {
          var _h;
          if ($window.innerWidth > 768) {
            _h = $window.innerHeight - 222 - element[0].nextElementSibling.clientHeight;
            $(element).css('height', _h + 'px');
          }
        };

        // Sibling height change.
        scope.$watch((function() {
          return element[0].nextElementSibling.clientHeight;
        }), (function(newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
          }
        }), true);

        // window resize.
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
          scope.calcCommentsHeight();
        });

        // Init.
        scope.calcCommentsHeight();
      }
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

Comment: how are you using this directive?

Answer (score 0):

One option: Create a service to store the one elements value, then read that service on the second element.

```
angular.module('whatever.module', []).service('ElementHeight', function() {
    var height = 0;
    return {
      height: function() { return height; },
      setHeight: function(newHeight) { height = newHeight }
    }
});
```

pseudo code example:

```
function ThisController(ElementHeight) {
    // set it to the height of the element, how depends on what you're doing.
    ElementHeight.setHeight(999,999);

    // to get the height
    newHeight = ElementHeight.height;
}
```